# What's the difference between compiling a PHP extension from php/php-src and PECL?

Tags: php, github, php-extension, pecl

Is there any difference between downloading and compiling a PHP extension from php/php-src (GitHub) or PECL?

I can clone php/php-src `checkout php-5.5.30` and build memcached extension. I can do the same with `pecl download memcached` and build from tha tarball. Would I get the same exact `.so` module?

Comment: This probably depends on the extension, git branch, etc.  The master branch of the extension may be ahead of the latest release on pecl.  For the memcached extension, it looks like neither has been touched in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

PECL take the same sources. But from Github you get the latest and newest version but normally that aren't stable releases and you should't use them in production. So PECL is fine.

Better is if its possible that you install the package over your package manager if you use a linux based distribution. Then you can be sure that the package is working with your version.

Comment: So, say I need to compile for php 5.5.30, would be better to checkout tag 5.5.30 from github and compiling memcached (or any other extension), or use PECL and download from it? What I can't really get is, if memcached downloaded from PECL is the latest version targeted for php 5.5, shouldn't used for any other PHP version (for example PHP 5.4.x)?

Comment: I wouldn't do nothing of them ;) i would install memcachd over the package manager. I use ubuntu or debian `apt-get install php5-memcached` is enough. The you get updates and don't need to recompile it every time.

Comment: Yep I know, but I need to compile it because I'm using "standalone" multiple PHP version (non global), ie installed in /opt...

Comment: I think you can both of them you should use a tagged and stable version. PECL is a bit better to update your packages so in your case i would prefer  PECL.